# String from model to javascript does not compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, paperclip

In rails, I am trying to get a URL from a model into my javascript in the view as a string. This is what I do currently.

```
#in the model
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { thumb: "60x60>"}, :default_url => "/system/users/avatars/thumb/missing.png"
#using paperclip gem.
....
def someMethod
   return [neares.map{|u| u.avatar.url(:thumb)}.compact]
end
```

Later in the view I do the following:

```
anArray = <%=aModelInstace.someMethod().to_json%>;
```

This is what I get in my rendered javascript:

```
//swap all the $ with &
anArray = [[$quot;/system/users/avatars/thumb/missing.png$quot;],[/* many similar to the previous */]];
```

This does not compile and causes an error, "unexpected token &". So how can I get this to return an actual string in javascript, and not just with the wrapped quot signs?

---

I have tried `u.avatar.url(:thumb).to_s` and `"#{u.avatar.url(:thumb)}"`. No luck. Also, hours of googling got me nowhere :(

Comment: Did you try `<%=raw your_json %>` ?

Comment: Rails has a method called `escape_javascript` too that might help. But I'll go with `raw` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As apneadiving and Benjamin Tan said:

Use:

> anArray = <%=raw aModelInstace.someMethod().to_json%>;

This solved the problem.

Comment: I can not even understand how I didn't remember that. Well, everything works well now. Consider writing as answer @apneadiving :)